# Rails Json ParseError even if the json was right

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I'm getting JSON ParseError even if the json to me is right.

Below the log with the error:

> JSON::ParserError (784: unexpected token at '"{"start":"2017-04-10T19:00:00","end":"2017-04-10T19:30:00","slot_id":"58ac958402e396b60400000a","ambulatory":"Test  Partners","price_private":120,"discount_private":0,"title":"Prenota (prezzo: 120 €)","doctor":"Dott. Mario Rossi","doctor_cv":"/curriculums/original/missing.png","source":{"url":"/get_slot_for_cal?id=58ac958402e396b604000002","type":"GET","className":[],"_fetchId":8,"_status":"resolved"},"_id":"_fc134","className":[],"allDay":false,"_allDay":false,"_start":"2017-04-10T19:00:00","_end":"2017-04-10T19:30:00"}"')

I tried also escaping the " character same error

Comment: Can you show the exact code producing this error?

Comment: Please add your JSON as well

Comment: Parsed well for me, using ruby 2.4. Try printing string before parsing. `puts raw_content`, make sure it don't have extra quotes